# Svelte component is not taking value from array individual value?

Tags: svelte

I have created a DataTableTest component

```
<script>
  export let title;
  export let data;
  export let columns = [];
</script>

{title}
<table>
  {#if columns}
    <tr>
      {#each columns as c}
        <td>{c.label}</td>
      {/each}
    </tr>
  {/if}
  {#if data}
    <tbody>
      {#each data as d, i}
        <tr>
          {#each columns as c}
              <td>
              {@html d[c.property] ? d[c.property] : ''}
              </td>
          {/each}
        </tr>
      {/each}
    </tbody>
  {/if}
</table>
```

I am trying to call this from another svelte file as follows:

```
{#each data as da}
{da}
    <DataTableTest title="Orders" {da} {columns} />
{/each}
```

Data is an array of array but somehow DataTableTest is always getting da as undefined. In this svelte file, I am creating the data array manually above.
If I use,

```
<DataTableTest title="Orders" {data} {columns} />
```

Then, it shows some empty lines in the DataTableTest, while da is not working. Print of {da} is working fine. I can see the data but with DataTableTest component its not working.

Comment: How are you setting your array? Maybe [check this](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects).

Comment: I am setting the array in pretty similar way like this example in the script tag above. Eg.   data = [[
    {}
  ], [
    {}, {}
  ]];

Comment: I am seeing on the UI with {da} as actual objects but not going through the DataTableTest component that I build?

Comment: This is the code: https://svelte.dev/repl/04fb7b68aa8440eaa6e47653c8c448f2?version=3.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the loop, you are setting `da` attribute, but it expects a `data` attribute.

Change:

```
<DataTableTest title="Orders" {da} {columns}/>
```

to:

```
<DataTableTest title="Orders" data={da} {columns}/>
```

Comment: wow ... this was a silly mistake I was doing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: haha, no worries, sometimes we all need another set of eyes :)